# Laravel Scout Search with FacetFilters?

Tags: php, laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

As you know, using `where()` statement after the search method uses `numericFilter`. I am trying to filter my search results with string filtering.

How can I use Facet Filter on search statement?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am glad to answer my own problem. First of all, it's really hard to find any doc about the Laravel Scout already. If you want to filter your search results with string parameters. Even it's really hard to find an answer too. I checked the whole library line by line.Finally, the result made me proud.

If you want to filter your result with string parameters you need to design callback function to your `search()` method and inject your **FacetFilters** on there.Simply, Let's assume you have `Posts` model that you are using Algolia and you have enum typed `category` column on it. You can filter your blog post search results with the code below.

```
$post = Post::search($query, function ($algolia, $query, $options) use ($category){
    $new_options = [];
    if (!is_null($type)) {
        $new_options = ["facetFilters"=>"category_name:".$category];
    }
    return $algolia->search($query, array_merge($options,$new_options));
});
```

Comment: thank you for your hard work! This really helped me. Just wanna say I also found a documentation regarding this. https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/laravel/extending-scout/

Comment: There is also a package maintained by algolia for macros. https://github.com/algolia/laravel-scout-algolia-macros

Comment: @bl4cksta do you mind share the docs? also what is "$type" in line 4 (inside if statement)? thanks!

Answer (score 4):

According to the algolia documentation you can modify the search parameters like this:

```
$results = Product::search($q)->with(
    [
        'facets' => ['*'],
        'facetFilters' => [$facetFilters],
    ]
)->paginate(24);
```

https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/laravel/searching/server-side-search/

Answer (score 1):

An answer here helped me. I want to share my code snippets, maybe it will help someone else. My model:

```
public function toSearchableArray()
{
    // Define the attributes you want to make searchable in Algolia
    return [
        'title' => $this->title,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'status' => $this->status,
        'address' => $this->address,
    ];
}

public function getScoutSettings()
{
    return [
        'attributesForFaceting' => [
            'filterOnly(status)',
            'filterOnly(address)',
            // Add other attributes for faceting
        ],
    ];
}
```

My search query:

```
$query = request('query');
$address = request('address');
$posts = Post::search($query, function ($algolia, $query, $options) use($address){
            $new_options = [
                "facetFilters"=>
                    ["status:1","address:".$address],
            ];
        return $algolia->search($query, array_merge($options,$new_options));
    })->paginate(12);
```